# macOS Music: Keyboard shortcuts: How to exit search? How to view library songs?

Tags: shortcut, search, music.app

I'm used to viewing my library songs and hitting command-f to filter the list.

Since upgrading from iTunes to Music this year, command-f triggers the bizarre new search that gives results as bubbles and grids. And I can't seem to exit it via tab or escape or command-shift-f for "filter".

- What's the keyboard shortcut to exit this new search (is there one)?
- Or, what's the keyboard shortcut to return to viewing my library songs? Apart from my playlists, it's the only view I ever want to see anyway. I don't subscribe to Apple Music or use iCloud to store my songs.
- Or, what text can I enter into system prefs for these actions to create custom shortcuts for them?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted without comment? Was it not written clearly enough? Is it not in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to get back the functionality Apple changed. Unless the majority of people push back, I'd start looking for another player. I love the cesium player on iOS and hope it comes to MacOS as well.

- https://www.csmusicplayer.com

It refines the iTunes design of old and shares the same source library so I can choose how I interact. My guess is the vast majority of people use Siri to queue up music - so if you have playlists and can enable "hey Siri" on your Mac or shift to another way of searching / navigating / queuing music due to the change being forced on you. Sorry I don't have better ideas or suggestion - hopefully someone else can suggest a player that fits your needs if my two don't work, but Music is moving away from your setup and towards Siri / Apple Music / iOS / AppleTV / HomePod integration and search/control/discovery. I use the following two items to play audio / video on local storage, but can't see them as a good fit for replacing how iTunes used to work.

- https://mpv.io/installation/
- https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html